# How to access QTableWidget created in for loop

Tags: python, pyqt5

I created different tabs using `QTableWidget` in a loop:

```
self.table_widget = QTableWidget()    
for i in range(0, 5):
     self.table_widget.tab = QWidget()
     self.table_widget.tabs.addTab(self.table_widget.tab, f"{i}")
     self.table_widget.tab.Layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
     self.tab_table = QTableWidget(self)
     self.table_widget.tab.Layout.addWidget(self.tab_table)
self.table_widget.tab.setLayout(self.table_widget.tab.Layout)
self.table_widget.show()
```

How can I access the `QTableWidget` inside the different tabs? Each tab does not have a specific `variable name`, which can be used to control the `widget`. I can get the `currentIndex` of the tab, but I don't know how to use this information.

Comment: Why do you have a tab widget as attribute of `self.table_widget`? And where are you creating it?

Comment: I create it in my `MainWindow` class. But I found the solution by using the `children` function on the `currentWidget`.

Comment: You didn't answer my first question. Why are you making a tab widget as attribute of a table?

Comment: I copied the code wrong. It is supposed to be `self.table_widget = QWidget()`. The naming of the variable could have been better selected

Comment: Yes, you should be much more careful in choosing names. Besides, your code is still confusing: there's no trace of the creation of the tab widget (`self.table_widget.tabs`), the layout is created with the wrong argument (`self`), and `setLayout` is called outside the loop (maybe an indentation error). For future reference, take your time to provide a carefully written code: it's better for you as it is for anybody else reading (and trying to answer) your question. We should be able to focus on answering the question, not understanding it or figuring out what's missing.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to create a list as an instance attribute, and add the table widgets to it. Note that there's no point in setting instance attributes in a loop, as they will be overwritten every time.

Also, you should not create a layout with a widget argument if you're going to set that layout to *another* widget.

```
self.tables = []
for i in range(5):
    tab = QWidget()
    self.table_widget.tabs.addTab(tab, f"{i}")
    layout = QVBoxLayout(tab)
    tab_table = QTableWidget()
    layout.addWidget(tab_table)
    self.tables.append(tab_table)
```

Alternatively, you can make the table an instance member of the page:

```
    for i in range(5):
        tab = QWidget()
        self.table_widget.tabs.addTab(tab, f"{i}")
        layout = QVBoxLayout(tab)
        tab.tab_table = QTableWidget()
        layout.addWidget(tab.tab_table)

def get_table(self, index):
    tab = self.table_widget.tabs.widget(index)
    return tab.tab_table
```

Another possibility, as long as it's guaranteed that each tab only has one table, is to use [`findChild()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild):

```
def get_table(self, index):
    tab = self.table_widget.tabs.widget(index)
    return tab.findChild(QTableWidget)
```